# How do I use Excel Solver with IF statements?

Tags: excel, solver

I have a table of tennis players where I've worked out the probability of them winning their respective matches in three different ways, e.g. % previous 10 games won, % first serves in play etc etc. I've assigned a weighting to each of these probabilities to create a blended probability which I convert into predicted odds. I then compare these predicted odds to the actual odds that are available from bookmakers  to derive the 'edge'. A positive edge means the bookmaker is offering better odds than they should and there is 'value' in placing a bet. There are a three potential scenarios:

1. Edge >= Edge threshold, player wins then I win £100 x actual odds
2. Edge >= Edge threshold, player loses then I lose £100
3. Edge < Edge threshold, I don't bet so neither win nor lose

I want to work out what the optimal combination of the three probabilities AND the edge threshold that generates the highest level of profit. I tried to use Excel Solver to do this but apparently it can't cope with IF statements. I've read in a few places that you can convert IF statements into complex formulas that get around this problem but I haven't been able find an example that's clear enough to follow. What are the potential solutions?

For reference here is a sample of the table:

```
+-----+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------+--------+-----------+-------------+
| PKG | Probability 1 | Probability 2 | Probability 3 | Blended probability | Predicted odds | Actuals odds |  Edge  | WIN/ LOSE | Overall P&L |
+-----+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------+--------+-----------+-------------+
|   1 | 32.4%         | 28.6%         | 74.0%         | 43.4%               |           2.31 |         2.81 |   7.86 |         1 |           0 |
|   2 | 36.2%         | 34.1%         | 61.0%         | 42.8%               |           2.34 |         4.47 |  20.39 |         0 |        -100 |
|   3 | 55.2%         | 58.2%         | 42.0%         | 52.4%               |           1.91 |         4.13 |  28.19 |         1 |         413 |
|   4 | 60.7%         | 64.7%         | 67.0%         | 64.2%               |           1.56 |         1.44 |  -5.17 |         0 |           0 |
|   5 | 33.7%         | 40.1%         | 75.0%         | 48.6%               |           2.06 |         2.32 |   5.57 |         1 |           0 |
|   6 | 48.7%         | 47.8%         | 77.0%         | 56.8%               |           1.76 |         3.41 |  27.46 |         0 |        -100 |
|   7 | 55.2%         | 64.1%         | 79.0%         | 65.9%               |           1.52 |         2.38 |  23.87 |         1 |         238 |
|   8 | 45.6%         | 34.9%         | 30.0%         | 36.6%               |           2.73 |         3.70 |   9.63 |         0 |           0 |
|   9 | 56.9%         | 63.1%         | 49.0%         | 57.0%               |           1.75 |         3.00 |  23.64 |         1 |         300 |
|  10 | 38.6%         | 37.6%         | 25.0%         | 34.1%               |           2.93 |         3.25 |   3.32 |         0 |           0 |
|  11 | 56.4%         | 56.4%         | 63.0%         | 58.4%               |           1.71 |         2.74 |  21.90 |         1 |         274 |
|  12 | 71.3%         | 78.1%         | 38.0%         | 64.1%               |           1.56 |         3.66 |  36.75 |         0 |        -100 |
|  13 | 61.4%         | 67.5%         | 72.0%         | 67.0%               |           1.49 |         1.23 | -14.50 |         1 |           0 |
|  14 | 66.4%         | 73.0%         | 76.0%         | 71.9%               |           1.39 |         1.42 |   1.46 |         0 |           0 |
|  15 | 56.1%         | 64.8%         | 21.0%         | 49.1%               |           2.04 |         1.35 | -25.19 |         1 |           0 |
|  16 | 61.5%         | 53.4%         | 57.0%         | 56.9%               |           1.76 |         1.37 |  21.03 |         0 |        -100 |
|  17 | 32.4%         | 26.2%         | 45.0%         | 33.7%               |           2.97 |         1.45 | -35.14 |         1 |           0 |
|  18 | 69.5%         | 62.5%         | 43.0%         | 58.8%               |           1.70 |         1.77 |   2.19 |         0 |           0 |
|  19 | 65.0%         | 65.3%         | 45.0%         | 59.1%               |           1.69 |         3.66 |  31.81 |         1 |         366 |
|  20 | 73.1%         | 81.9%         | 45.0%         | 68.2%               |           1.47 |         1.12 | -21.03 |         0 |           0 |
|  21 | 52.2%         | 51.4%         | 25.0%         | 43.7%               |           2.29 |         2.59 |   5.14 |         1 |           0 |
|  22 | 30.9%         | 38.2%         | 27.0%         | 32.6%               |           3.06 |         2.26 | -11.61 |         0 |           0 |
|  23 | 61.6%         | 43.1%         | 46.0%         | 49.5%               |           2.02 |         2.82 |  14.11 |         1 |           0 |
|  24 | 58.6%         | 73.4%         | 34.0%         | 57.1%               |           1.75 |         4.21 |  33.38 |         0 |        -100 |
|  25 | 64.4%         | 72.8%         | 61.0%         | 66.7%               |           1.50 |         2.24 |  21.99 |         1 |         224 |
+-----+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------+--------+-----------+-------------+
```

Here are the weightings:

```
+---------------+-----------+
|     Blend     | Weighting |
+---------------+-----------+
| Probability 1 | 30.0%     |
| Probability 2 | 40.0%     |
| Probability 3 | 30.0%     |
+---------------+-----------+
```

Predicted odds are calculated using the following formula:

`=1/Blend prob`

The edge is calculated using the following formula:

`=(100/Pred odds)-(100/Act odds)`

The current edge threshold is 20.

The IF statement to calculate the Overall P&L is:

`=IF(WIN/LOSE=1,IF(Edge>=Edge threshold,100*Act odds,0),IF(Edge>=Edge threshold,-100,0))`

I set up Solver as follows:

1. Objective: Max of a cell that summed the Overall P&L cells
2. Variables: i ) the weightings cells above as fixed values and ii) a cell with the edge threshold as a fixed value
3. Constants: A cell that sums the weightings - set at 1 (100%) and the Edge threshold as an integer
4. Method: Tried GRG Nonlinear and Evolutionary (the latter is one that is supposed to be able to handle 'non-smooth' problems, i.e. IF statements)

Comment: What did you try? You are just exposing your problem and it seems that there is no work from your side except some research.

Comment: I tried Excel Solver which told me the solution was solved but didn't change any of the variables. Looking online it seems that the free version can't cope with IF statements...

Comment: Done! Added to the original question...

Comment: is the sum of the three weightings must be 100% or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have tested your sample data using **Solver** with the following set up:

[image: Attempt2]

The Variables range is `C29:C32` (the three weightings and the threshold);

The constraints are:

- `C29:C31<=1` as they are probabilities;
- `C32<=100` must set an upper bound for this variable so I picked `100` which should be safe?
- `C33=1` which is the sum of the three weightings which should be 100% exact?

Use **Evolutionary** method I have obtained the following:

- Max Profit: `2210`;
- Probability 1: `37.5%`
- Probability 2: `9.1%`
- Probability 3: `53.4%`
- Threshold: `18`

> I think the WIN/LOSS result plays a significant role in this exercise but what would be the reasonable constraints for this range except `binary`?

Comment: Me too. So if it is working, what is your real problem?

Comment: This is great, thank you. It was the addition of the constraint that stated that each of the % weightings had to be <=1 that did the trick! Would you mind explaining why? Was it that Solver simply had too many combinations to analyse without this constraint and so gave up?

Comment: On the WIN/LOSS question - it will only ever be binary but I thought you could only add constraints to variables?

Comment: Hi guys - not sure if you saw my question?

Comment: @Jossy yes and I gave some thoughts over it. Firstly it is necessary to set a constraint to each criteria. The weighting is a probability and you used them to derive a blended probability so the total of the three weightings should be 100% if you believe the three criteria are the only determinants of the result. If you alter the WIN/LOSS result to the opposite, you will get a different outcome. That's why I said you probably want to set them as variables but give a reasonable constraint for example the total WIN will be no more than 13 (being 50% of the total games)? Let me know how you go :)

Answer (score 0):

I came upon this old question and thought I'd at least try it out and perhaps answer some of the open questions:
It worked using the Evolutionary method on the first try.
Just to be sure of the logic, I read it as:

You only bet if the Actual odds are higher than the predicted odds.
If you bet and if the player wins the match then there is a profit.
If you bet and if the player loses the match then there is a loss.

It appears that the (player) WIN/LOSE column was sequentially generated to give equal probability of the *player* winning or losing by alternating the entries.
I'm not sure it's the best simulation if the "don't care" Edge < Edge Threshold cases are included - because they can't contribute to the results - (but do contribute to the simulation).  My recommendation would be to run a large enough set of cases where the players WIN/LOSE vector is randomized in order to see how widely distributed the outcomes can be using this weighting and betting method.
It appears that the calculation for Edge in PKG=16 is incorrect - I fixed it here.
Both GRG Nonlinear and Evolutionary work on this problem.  I see not reason why having "IF" statements within the cells should make a difference.
[image]